# Minimum value of expression containing $2$ variables $x,y$

Tags: calculus

> Finding minimum of $\displaystyle f(a,b)= (a-b)^2+\bigg(\frac{a^2}{20}-\sqrt{(17-b)(b-13)}\bigg)^2,$
>   where $a\in\mathbb{R^{+}},b\in(13,17)$ 
>   (Without using Geometry)

Try: Using partial derivative with r to $a$ (Treating $b$ as a constant)
$\displaystyle f'(a,b)= 2(a-b)+2\bigg(\frac{a^2}{20}-\sqrt{(17-b)(b-13)}\bigg)\cdot \frac{a}{10}$

Using partial derivative with r to $b$(Treating $a$ as a constant)
$\displaystyle f'(a,b)= -2(a-b)+2\bigg(\frac{a^2}{20}-\sqrt{(17-b)(b-13)}\bigg)\cdot (2b-30)$(Treating $b$ as a constant)

Could some help me to solve it, thanks

Comment: The general approach is to compare the values of the function at critical points (where derivatives are zero or do not exist) with its values on the boundary of its domain.  Any progress on either of those evaluations?

Comment: the minimum is given by $$2(27-10\sqrt{2})$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As analysis teaches us, take the derivatives with respect to $a$ and $b$ separately, and converge them into a system of equations imposing them to be zero:

$$\begin{cases}
\large \frac{a^3}{100}+a \left(2-\frac{1}{5} \sqrt{-b^2+30 b-221}\right)-2 b = 0\\\\
\large \frac{a^2 (b-15)}{10 \sqrt{-b^2+30 b-221}}-2 a+30 = 0
\end{cases}$$

Now you have to solve them both for $a$ and $b$

One of the solutions (the only real one) is simple and it's

$$a = 10$$

$$b = 15 - \sqrt{2}$$

Substituting those values into the initial equation gives you the minimum value which is

$$f(10, 15 - \sqrt{2}) = \left(\sqrt{2}-5\right)^2+\left(5-\sqrt{\left(2-\sqrt{2}\right) \left(\sqrt{2}+2\right)}\right)^2 = \color{red}{54 - 20\sqrt{2}}$$

As Dr. Sonnhard Gaubner already told you.

Comment: Dear Mr. Neumann, my first name is Sonnhard

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I beg your pardon, I used the phone and the auto-corrector spelled your name wrong -.-

Comment: then the auto-corrector was wrong and not you! Nice to meet you!